# why parentViewController, presentingViewController and PresentedViewController are always nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I have a simple app with several ViewControllers for which I need to know from which VC I come from when I am in a VC (except the first one). All VCs are created in the storyboard and I navigate through VCs with the code below :

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController
{    
    func ShowStartVC()
    {
        if gFirstStart
        {
            let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EvalUserLevelVC") as EvalUserLevelVC
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChoixLevelVC") as ChoixLevelVC
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func ShowPrefsVC()
    {
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PrefsVC") as PrefsVC
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


class FirstVCSceneClass: SKScene
{
    var VCFirst = FirstVC?()

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {    
        for touch: AnyObject in touches
        {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            switch self.nodeAtPoint(location).name!
            {
            case "Start":
                VCFirst?.ShowStartVC()
                self.paused = true

            case "Preferences":
                VCFirst?.ShowPrefsVC()
                self.paused = true

            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above the "ChoixLevelVC" can be called from here and from another VC (exactly the same way) and I need to know from which VC it has been called. My understanding is that the property "presentingViewController" should have this information when I access it from the "ChoixLevelVC" UIViewController class

But if I put the below code in "ChoixLevelVC" everything is at nil although I would expect to find "FirstVC" in the property "presentingViewController"

```
class ChoixLevelVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        println("ParentViewController : \(self.parentViewController)")
        println("presentingViewController : \(self.presentingViewController)")
        println("presentedViewController : \(self.presentedViewController)")
    }
}
```

And it is the same in every VC. Is there something I need to do in order to have these properties correctly set up ?

Comment: Are the println statements in a UIViewController subclass or a SKScene subclass?

Comment: The println are in the viewdidload func of each UIViewController subclass. Edit made to make it more clear

Comment: Was there ever an update on this problem? I'm having the same problem accessing my presentingVC from my modalVC.